# Error delimiting EOF

Tags: bash, shell

I´m having < hard time with this bash script which was working, but since I refactor start comlining because the EOF that I´m using

```
     #!/bin/bash -v

    get_aws(){
                cd /home/ec2-user/
                wget https://repo/aws_git
                chmod 600 aws_git
                wget https://repo/aws_config
                yum install -y expect
                secret="aws_config"
                pass=$(cat $secret)
                eval $(ssh-agent)
                /usr/bin/expect<<EOF --> this is the line that complain
                    spawn ssh-add aws_git
                    expect "Enter passphrase"
                    send "$pass\r"
                    expect eof
                    spawn git clone git@github.repo.git
                    expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting"
                    send "yes\r"
                    expect eof
                EOF
                echo "finish" --> this line it colored as it was all String
            }

     get_aws
```

The error says line 13 it´s delimited by end-of-file (expected `EOF')
Any idea? I cannot see the error

Regards.

Comment: Put a `-` between `<<` and `EOF`: `/usr/bin/expect<<-EOF`

Comment: nope, same problem, but thanks

Comment: Are you using spaces for indentation? Then you must unindent your delimiting `EOF`, by moving it to the beginning of the line.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem!, thanks a lot, I cpompletlly forgot that inside EOF it´s treated as String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The - option to mark a here document limit string (<<-LimitString)
>   **suppresses leading tabs (but not spaces)** in the output. This may be
>   useful in making a script more readable.
>
> **The closing limit string, on the final line of a here document, must
>   start in the first character position. There can be no leading
>   whitespace**. Trailing whitespace after the limit string likewise causes
>   unexpected behavior. The whitespace prevents the limit string from
>   being recognized

Check [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)